# Visual Studio 11 beta: some JavaScript templates missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I started playing with Windows 8 Metro with Visual Studio 11 beta. I created a blank Javascript (Metro style) project and tried to add an "HTML Fragment" item. The problem is that this template item is not present and I can not select it.

I looked in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\JavaScript\Windows Metro style\1033* folder and it contains a file Fragment.zip.

My environment: Virtual Box VM with Windows 8 consumer preview and Visual Studio 11 beta + SDK.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.